# How to map List<int> into property of complex type using Automapper?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have this data model:

```
public class ObjectType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectType> AllowedSubTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to use Automapper to map the following DTO model into the above data model:

```
public class ObjectTypeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<int> AllowedTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how to map List of integer into the List AllowedSubTypes only for Id property?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a specific mapping from the `List` of `int` to the `list` of `ObjectType` and also create the map between the data model and the DTO class.

```
x.CreateMap<ObjectTypeDto, ObjectType>()
    .ForMember(m => m.AllowedSubTypes, mv => mv.MapFrom(m => m.AllowedTypes));

x.CreateMap<int, ObjectType>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Id, mv => mv.MapFrom(m => m));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried it out but I have got this exception "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."